# Optimizing Quick Sort (in python)

Tags: python, sorting, optimization, quicksort

I am trying to write a Quick Sort based sorting algorithm using python. Here I'm giving two codes on Quick Sort.....

```
def insertion_sort(arr, l, r):
    """ binary insertion sort """
    ....

def partition_func(arr, l, r):
    ....
```

**First One**

```
def traditional_quicksort(arr, l, r, partition, insertionsort):
    while r-l > 16:
        m = partition(arr, l, r)
        if (m-l) < (r-m):
            traditional_quicksort(arr, l, m-1, partition, insertionsort)
            l = m + 1
        else:
            traditional_quicksort(arr, m+1, r, partition, insertionsort)
            r = m - 1
    insertionsort(arr, l, r)
```

**Second One**

```
def new_quicksort(arr, l, r, partition, insertionsort):
    m = r+1
    # usually m means the point of partition
    # but if r-l > 32 then m won't mean the point of partition
    while (r-l) > 32:
        m = partition(arr, l, r)
        pre_m = m
        if (pre_m - l) < (r - pre_m):
            m, _ = partition(arr, pre_m+1, r), new_quicksort(arr, l, pre_m-1, partition, insertionsort)
            l = pre_m + 1
        else:
            m, _ = partition(arr, l, pre_m-1), new_quicksort(arr, pre_m+1, r, partition, insertionsort)
            r = pre_m - 1
    if m > r:
        # that means m is not the point of partition
        # and so we should use insertion sort from index l to r
        insertionsort(arr, l, r)
    else:
        insertionsort(arr, l, m - 1)
        insertionsort(arr, m + 1, r)
```

I'm actually not sure how ',' works in python, but I guessed that putting partition function and quicksort function separated by a ',' might be an optimized version of the traditional one. But the result in my pc showed something different. I copied the partition function from [programiz.com](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/quick-sort) and used python's default Timsort as the Insertion Sort (just for temporary testing).
Using the timeit function (number=5, length=131072, shuffled using random.shuffle),

traditional_quicksort: 1.53832088 s
new_quicksort: 3.58588982 s
(on an average!)

It shows that the latter one is slower than the former. So, whether new_quicksort is badly optimized, or for some other reason it is seeming to be slow?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
You're asking multiple questions, including opinions on "better" -- which you haven't defined, and other inappropriate, open-ended items.

Comment: Have you verified whether your sort functions sort correctly? Your `traditional_quicksort` doesn't look _traditional_ and doesn't look correct to me, since it sorts only the left hand or the right hand subarray instead of both.

Comment: @Armali both of them works perfectly

Comment: When I try your `traditional_quicksort`, I get e. g. `[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 15, 11, 2, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18]`, which doesn't look _perfect_ to me.

Comment: @Armali please check out the code [here](https://code.sololearn.com/c0a22A5A20a2/?ref=app). Sorry, I don't see any bug in it. But if you find any issue then do let me know. Thanks!

Comment: The `traditional_quicksort` you linked to is not the same as you posted in the question.

Comment: Now I see that the programiz.com/dsa/quick-sort algorithm pseudo code (which I used) has an error which is not present in the "Quicksort Code in Python" further down the page.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm actually not sure how ',' works in python, but I guessed that putting partition function and quicksort function separated by a ',' might be an optimized version of the traditional one.

Guessing in programming is often not helpful.

> So, whether new_quicksort is badly optimized, or for some other reason it is seeming to be slow?

```
    while (r-l) > 32:
        m = partition(arr, l, r)
        pre_m = m
        if (pre_m - l) < (r - pre_m):
            m, _ = partition(arr, pre_m+1, r), new_quicksort(arr, l, pre_m-1, partition, insertionsort)
            l = pre_m + 1
        else:
            m, _ = partition(arr, l, pre_m-1), new_quicksort(arr, pre_m+1, r, partition, insertionsort)
            r = pre_m - 1
```

is equivalent to

```
    while (r-l) > 32:
        m = partition(arr, l, r)
        pre_m = m
        if (pre_m - l) < (r - pre_m):
            m = partition(arr, pre_m+1, r)
            new_quicksort(arr, l, pre_m-1, partition, insertionsort)
            l = pre_m + 1
        else:
            m = partition(arr, l, pre_m-1)
            new_quicksort(arr, pre_m+1, r, partition, insertionsort)
            r = pre_m - 1
```

We see that in all loop runs but the first the `partition(arr, l, r)` call has the same argument values as the other `partition()` call from the previous run (due to the `l = pre_m + 1` or `r = pre_m - 1`); so a main reason for the slowness of `new_quicksort` may well be that unnecessarily repeated `partition`.